# Oracle HTP.formopen PLS-00306

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle web PLS-SQL package body that compiles successfully.  When executed, get an ORA-06550 & PLS 00306 error "Wrong Number or types of arguments in call".  The call is HTP.formopen (code below).  Since there is no "arquments", what is wrong with this call?

Updated question, how do I pass parameters to a function inside HTP.formopen?

```
   HTP.formopen (twbkwbis.f_cgibin || 'bzskaold.FS_P_ProcessRequest');

-------

   TYPE varchar2_hashtab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(5);
   TYPE varchar2_tabtype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(26) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   var_empty_hash  varchar2_hashtab;
   var_empty_table varchar2_tabtype;

   PROCEDURE FS_P_ProcessRequest
   (
     AA   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     BB   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     CC   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     DD   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     EE   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     FF   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     GG   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     HH   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     II   IN OUT  bzskaold.varchar2_hashtab,
     JJ   IN      bzskaold.varchar2_tabtype DEFAULT var_empty_table,
     KK   IN OUT  bzskaold.varchar2_hashtab,
     LL   IN      bzskaold.varchar2_tabtype DEFAULT var_empty_table,
     MM   IN OUT  bzskaold.varchar2_hashtab,
     NN   IN OUT  bzskaold.varchar2_hashtab,
     OO   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     PP   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     QQ   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     RR   IN      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
   );
```

Comment: htp.formopen has like 4 or 5 input parameters and you're only sending it one

Comment: To clarify, the error is FS_P_ProcessRequest is not passing the correct number of arguments when using HTP.formopen, not HTP.formopen having the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @selpatS20 - as written, FS_P_ProcessRequest must have the II, KK, MM, and NN parameters supplied when it is called, because these parameters don't have default values.

Comment: I updated my question with how do I pass those variables inside a formopen call.